A sharp object by guessing letters
Three unknown letters to get to a six letter sharp object. What are those and explain why. Some creative thinking may be needed


The answer is

 ICICLE

The top is just

 Roman Numerals in order so the letter after X is L.

The middle

 Is a well known mathematical formula PI x D (Diameter)= C (circumference)

The bottom

 Is the Albert Einstein equation E=mc^2…

The creative thinking

 The three vertical lines being Is can can be added in the white circle, and when added on the horizontal line it makes an L… the letters therefore are I,C,E making ICE.


While your final result is right, you have come up with 4 letters instead of the 3 that were asked for. How do you turn the 4 to 3? Thanks. BTW That was the creative thinking part.

Oh i see my bad…

Is it just adding three Is?

Yes you got the gist
